# Angular 9 ngOnChange: SimplesChanges.firstChange is always false but the value changed

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I have this component. I want to do something just the first time the `@Input` changes. The problem is that the `changes.firstChange` is always false (on init and after changed).

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './t.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./t.component.css']
})
export class TComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  myValue: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('myValue:  ', changes.myValue.isFirstChange()); // always false
    console.log('myValue:  ', changes);
  }

}
```

For using it, I'm doing:

```
  myValue = of('1').pipe(
    delay(2000),
    // startWith('2')
   )
```

I also tried:

```
  myValue = '1'
```

`<test [myValue]="myValue | async "></test>` // When using `of`

As you can see in the images `changes.firstChange` is always false, no matter if I pass a string or a new value later.

These are the outputs:
[image]

[image]

And this is the output when using the rxjs value:(value changed but never changed firstChange to true

[image]

Answer (score 0):

because that haven't previousValue

Comment: at some point there's a first change. It starts with null and then it has a string value.
Even if the `startWith` is enabled, the problem is the same. or just passing a string too.